# How do I find duplicate rows, and at the same time distinct?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query question.

I have a table with first name, last name and mobile numbers of clients.

```
Thor   Prestby   98726364
Thor   Prestby   98726364
Lars   Testrud   12938485
Lise   Robol     12938485
```

I want to find rows with the same mobile number, that have different names. As you see above Thor has 2 rows, and that's right. Lars and Lise have the same mobile number and that is what I want to find.

Comment: Can you describe the table structure (column names)? Also, what queries did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much outlined yourself the actions needed to take in your question.

In a nutshell

- use a subselect to get all the distinct rows
- group on mobilenumber from this unique resultset from the subselect
- retain only those mobilenumbers that occur at least twice

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT mobilenumber, COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT mobilenumber, firstname, lastname
         FROM   YourTable
       ) AS q
GROUP BY
       mobilenumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: SELECT mobilenumber, COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT mobilenumber, firstname, lastname
         FROM   YourTable
       ) AS q
GROUP BY
       mobilenumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: SELECT mobilenumber, COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT mobilenumber, firstname, lastname
         FROM   YourTable
       ) AS q
GROUP BY
       mobilenumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  Did the trick. I want to update to..replace the mobilenumber fild with NULL

Comment: @user2861571 - For wich user? All? On what RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using MS SQL Server here but you could use:

```
Declare @t table
(
FirstName varchar(100),
LastName varchar(100),
Mobile bigint
)

Insert Into @t
values ('Thor','Prestby',98726364),
        ('Thor','Prestby',   98726364),
        ('Lars','Testrud',12938485),
        ('Lise','Robol', 12938485),
        ('AN','Other', 12345868)

Select Mobile
From @t
Group By Mobile
Having Count(*) > 1

EXCEPT

Select Mobile
From @t
Group By FirstName, LastName, Mobile
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM the_table tt
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM the_table xx
  WHERE xx.mobineno = tt.mobileno
  AND (xx.fname <> tt.fname OR xx.lname <> tt.lname)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

For this records:

```
Thor   Prestby   98726364
Thor   Prestby   98726364
Lars   Testrud   12938485
Lise   Robol     12938485
AN     Other     12345868
```

Try it:

```
select  t.mobile, count(*) from new_table t
where t.mobile in
   (select  t1.mobile from new_table t1
     where t1.mobile=t.mobile
    group by   t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.mobile
   having count(*)=1)
group by t.mobile
having count(*)>1
```

You will get this result:

```
12938485     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.phone, count(t1.phone) CountNo
FROM (SELECT distinct * FROM YourTable) t1
Left Outer Join YourTable t2 ON t1.phone = t2.phone AND ( t1.FirstName <> t2.FirstName OR  t1.LastName <> t2.LastName)
WHERE t2.FirstName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.phone
HAVING count(t1.phone) > 1
ORDER BY CountNo desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using standard SQL syntax and joins to achieve the results

**Setup:**

```
create table dummy
(
firstname varchar2(20),
lastname varchar2(20),
phone number
);

insert into dummy values('Thor','Prestby',98726364);
insert into dummy values('Thor','Prestby',98726364);
insert into dummy values('Lars','Testrud',12938485);
insert into dummy values('Lise','Robol',12938485);
```

**Query:**

```
select a.firstname,a.lastname,a.phone from dummy a inner join dummy b 
on a.phone=b.phone and a.firstname != b.firstname and a.lastname != b.lastname;
```

**Result**

```
FIRSTNAME            LASTNAME             PHONE                  
-------------------- -------------------- ---------------------- 
Lise                 Robol                12938485               
Lars                 Testrud              12938485
```